# Replicate 2010 Globally Reusable Workflows in Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, active-directory

I'm trying to replicate the 2010 Approval and Collect Feedback globally reusable workflows in Designer 2013 as 2013 workflows. These "native" workflows feature a people picker that accesses our active directory. I'm stumped trying to replicate this feature in a 2013 design.

Can anyone help me understand how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For Designer workflow 2013, you shall be able to assign task to users and start an approval process. I am not sure what issue you are coming across. More information will be help.

And here are some examples for Designer 2013 workflow for approval. You can follow them and have Antone try.

https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

https://sharepointdiv.wordpress.com/2019/02/12/sharepoint-2013-2016-approval-workflow-with-3-dynamically-determined-approves-using-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll ask another way. Are there out-of-box 2013 workflows similar to 2010 workflows? For example, is there an out-of-box 2013 Approval workflow similar to the 2010 Approval workflow?

Comment: @JohnLute, Unfortunately, the answer is no. The only built-in approval workflow is in 2010.